# What is wrong with the following binary search tree insert method?

Tags: c, search, tree, insert, binary

```
///// bst.h /////

typedef struct BStree_node {
    Key key;
    Data data;
    struct BStree_node *left, *right;
}
BStree_node;

typedef BStree_node** BStree;


///// bst.c /////

BStree_node *new_node(Key key, Data data) {
    BStree_node *node;
    node = (BStree_node *) malloc(sizeof(BStree_node));
    node->key = key;
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

void bs_tree_insert(BStree bst, Key_Type key, Data_Type data) {
    bst_insert_helper(*bst, key, data);
}

void bst_insert_helper(BStree_node *node_ptr, Key_Type key, Data_Type data) {
    if ( node_ptr == NULL ) {
        node_ptr = new_node(key, data);
    }
    else {
        if ( key_comparison(key, node_ptr->key) < 0 )
            bst_insert_helper(node_ptr->left, key, data);
        else if ( key_comparison(key, node_ptr->key) > 0 )
            bst_insert_helper(node_ptr->right, key, data);
        else
        ;
    }
}
```

I am confused what is wrong with this code.

The original method bs_tree_insert takes in the parameters key, data and bst (of type BStree which is a pointer to a BStree_node). So in order to use recursion to insert a new node I called the bst_insert_helper method with (*bst) which is a pointer to the root node right?

Then the bst_insert_helper method recursively finds a spot to insert the node. Apparently this code has an error but I am unsure of where.

I am thinking maybe that I would need to build a helper method that takes in a new subtree instead of a node each time but I don't understand how that would be different than just taking a node as they are linked.

Comment: Why `typedef BStree_node** BStree` and not `typedef BStree_node* BStree` ?

Comment: This: `node_ptr = create_new_node(key, data);` - means *nothing* to the caller, The *callers*pointer remains unchanged as it was passed by value, and you leak memory as an added dose of salt in the wound. Also, post *real* code. There is no `bst_insert` in this post, yet you're calling it from `bs_tree_insert`

Comment: @WhozCraig apologies, I meant to call the helper method from the tree insert method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a helper. In fact, you need to *lose* one. Your entry function takes a `BStree_node**` (inconveniently hidden in a type alias), and that's exactly what you need to insert with modification to the callers pointer, passed by address, intact.

```
void bs_tree_insert(BStree bst, Key_Type key, Data_Type data) 
{
    if (*bst == NULL)
    {
        *bst = create_new_node(key, data);
    }
    else
    {
        int cmp = key_comparison(key, (*bst)->key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            bst_tree_insert(&(*bst)->left, key, data);
        else if (0 < cmp)
            bst_tree_insert(&(*bst)->right, key, data);
        // else equivalent; no duplicates
    }
}
```

The fact that you're hiding your pointer types in aliases makes this *harder*, not easier, to understand. I *strongly* suggest avoiding doing that. C programmers want to see asterisks, the calling card of pointer operations.